# getting updated records from last 2 hours

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large amount of data in my MongoDB and I want to query those records which were updated in the last 2 hours. can someone help

Comment: Are you using Mongoose or a normal MongoDB?

Comment: @NicholasD normal MongoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. First, add an `updatedAt` attribute at your collection. But I assume that you already have this.

So, in short:

```
db.collection.find({ "updatedAt" : { $lt: new Date(Date.now() - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000) } })
```

If you did not have an `updatedAt` attribute, then this one is also possible.

```
db.collection.find({ $where: function () { 
  return Date.now() - this._id.getTimestamp() < (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  
} })
```

Explanation:

1. You will find all documents whose `updatedAt` attribute is **less than 7200** seconds.
2. You will find all documents whose `ObjectID` is **less than 7200** seconds.

Remember that `ObjectID`'s timestamp can be retrieved.